# why does `awk` print all elements of a for loop, but can't export them all to the clipboard?

Tags: bash, awk, clipboard

Given some data like so:

```
"Something something","1234567890123456","12/34/5678","Other thing","123",""
```

I'm trying to get `awk` to print the fields and then export them to the `X` clipboard using `xclip` with the following:

```
echo $data | sed 's/"//g' | awk -F',' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) {print $i; system("echo \"" $i "\" | xclip -i")}}'
```

which correctly gives the right output:

```
Something something
1234567890123456
12/34/5678
Other thing
123
```

but it seems to only copy the last field to the clipboard. I am using a clipboard manager (`klipper`) so I would expect there to be all of the fields listed.

What am I missing?

Comment: You are running `xclip -i` once for each line of input. Is `xclip -i` incremental or does each run replace the clipboard contents? Did you mean to us `| xclip -i` on the output from `awk`?

Comment: your awk command will not run. the `for loop` syntax is wrong`(for i=1;i<NF;i++) `

Comment: You have several issues in your awk script unrelated to your xclip issue. Read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins if you are going to be using awk.

Comment: @wxl it should be `for(i=1;i<NF;i++)`  not `(for i=1;i<NF;i++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an `awk` issue at all. Apparently, `xclip` can't handle the speed of the input its receiving. Similarly, `for i in {1..3}; do echo $i | xclip -i; done` fails in just the same way. Adding a `sleep` after the call to `xclip` will solve the problem. Based on my experiments, there will need to be 0.1 seconds per item, so for 6 fields shown, you would need:

```
echo $data | sed 's/"//g' | awk -F',' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) {print $i; system("echo \"" $i "\" | xclip -i; sleep 0.6")}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to copy the fields to the clipboard with newlines between each value, then consider this:

```
awk -F',' '
  { s=$1; for (i=2;i<NF;i++) {s=s "\n"$i; }
    print s;
    system("echo \"" s "\" | xcopy -i");
  }'
```

Comment: with the clipboard manager, i can copy something, copy something else, copy a third thing and they're all on the clipboard manager, with the last thing being the active paste. so what i need is not newlines delimited text in a single copy to the clipboard, but separate ones.